# How to parse soap response message?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, soap

I want to parse the following xml snippet. Can anyone help me out in this. I am not getting how to parse through the  elements and all and just retrieve the  and EmployeeId nodes and its values

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xxx/yyy" xmlns:idi="http://xxxx/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <idi:retrieve>
         <requestXML>
            <CustomerNumber>111</CustomerNumber>
            <EmployeeId>222</EmployeeId>
         </requestXML>
      </idi:retrieve>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please see the xml above and give some hinte to parse this.
Thank you

Comment: have u ever tried using an XML parser?

Comment: I don't know what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a framework that knows to create an object model from a WSDL and do the parsing for you - that is the best course of action.

Just google on any of these:

- Axis2
- JAX-WS
- JAX-RPC

Choose one and use it.